# OpenCV HLS youtube stream stops after a couple frames

Tags: python, opencv, youtube, http-live-streaming, pafy

I'm trying to get a Youtube live stream to work with openCV but after 10 frames it just stopes and restarts after 2 minutes.

Error messages:

```
[tls @ 000001676fa27400] Unable to read from socket
[tls @ 000001676fa27400] Writing encrypted data to socket failed
[tls @ 000001676fa27400] Failed to send close message
```

Code used:

```
import cv2
import pafy

url = 'https://youtube.com/watch?v=51djMAqsmIQ'
vPafy = pafy.new(url)
play = vPafy.getbest()

print(play.url)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(play.url)
while (True):
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break    

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

i did also encounter this problem also with live HSL streams from youtube.

I did use a work around:

https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink/issues/857

In this case, i used streamlink to make a file /tmp/stream.
With opencv i am reading the file /tmp/stream..

(downside: you have to stop the stream otherwise the file is getting big)